# Derive values from a graph

Tags: sensor, graph

[image]
I want to get accurate values from this graph when the input voltage (mV) is 0mV what should the output voltage(V) be? I can guess by saying it's 2.55V but I need accurate values to make my circuit more accurate.
I plotted the graph on Excel but it was no good. I had never done anything like this before, and I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the correct direction to figure out how to solve something like this. I had another idea that I draw this graph but I really don't want to.

This graph is from an isolated amplifier: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809300216_Texas-Instruments-AMC1200BDWVR_C79905.pdf

Comment: The output differential voltage is clearly designed to be 0 when the differential input is 0. The extent to which this is true is limited by offset error.

Comment: Used to use a program called Datathief to convert graphs like yours to x & y values. worked very well.

Comment: The AMC1200 outputs a differential signal. If you want to get a single-ended signal, you need to add a difference amplifier or instrumentation amplifier like the INA154 or INA317. If you do not know what this means, ask a new question.

Comment: @CL. Hey, Yep it does, however, i will not be measuring a shunt with it but only measuring voltage and it will never go negative so on the high voltage side the inverting analogue input is grounded and only the non-inverting analogue input is used, likewise with the output however the inverting analogue output is not grounded it is just left floating.

Comment: @ManeGote This does not matter; the output of the AMC1200 always is differential.

Comment: @CL. okay, to improve my circuit I should add difference amplifier to the low side inverting and Non-inverting analogue output and keep the high side inverting analogue input grounded?

Comment: @ManeGote Correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph only shows typical values. You cannot depend on those values being accurate for any given sample of the chip. If you read the datasheet you linked, you will find this line:

[image]

So for a 4.5V to 5.5V supply the output common mode voltage will be somewhere between 2.4V and 2.7V, with 2.55V being "typical" at 25°C & at 5.0V supply.

Note that you should not have any expectation of the common mode voltage being stable with respect to temperature or power supply voltage (or even time) unless it's guaranteed by the datasheet in some way. In fact, it's implied it varies considerably with power supply voltage.

Generally speaking, you should use it in such a way that the common mode voltage (within the guaranteed range) has *minimal* effect on your circuit. Your circuit should respond to the *differential* output voltage and reject the common mode output voltage.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter you are looking for is the Common-Mode output voltage. This is given in the datasheet you linked to:

[image: Common Mode Voltage]

For a 4.5V to 5.5V supply, it is nominally 2.55V, however can be anywhere from 2.4V to 2.7V depending on temperature and process variations.

If this value is critical for your circuit you will need to have some way of tuning and calibrating every circuit board individually as the value will vary from part to part.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are of course correct, but I will answer your direct question (because that can be useful as well).

Tools to use:

- [WebPlotDigitizer](https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/ankitrohatgi/WebPlotDigitizer)) (works in the browser but also available as an app)
- [Engauge Digitizer](https://markummitchell.github.io/engauge-digitizer/) (this is a desktop app, and was the first instance I stumbled upon years ago)

I don't have any affiliation with the tools, I just used them and found them useful.

A query to find things like this: "plot digitizer" or variants thereof.